# Block Incoming Calls in ios7

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

Since Call blocking feature has been introduced by apple in ios 7 , is there any way or API through which call blocking can be achieved programmatically ??

Comment: God I hope not, what business does an app have screening my calls? (That said, the answer will probably be found in the SDK docs. I'd start with the API diffs: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS70APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013203)

Comment: Skimming the docs it sems that all you get (and this isn't new) is an event telling you your app was suspended because of an incoming call.